# dotnet restore dependency resolution not pulling latest version

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a dependency chain that looks like this, I'm using dotnet restore (as apposed to Nuget restore) within my CI/CD chain

Project A (csproj) -> Project B (nuspec) -> Project C (csproj)

- Project A refers to Project B with <PackageReference Include="Project B" Version="2.*/>
- Project B refers to Project C with <dependency id="Project C" version="2.*/>

I always get the correct (latest) version of Project B but the restore always pulls the lowest version on Project C

I've tried adding --no-cache and --force-evaluate to the dotnet command line

Comment: Actually, the behavior can be controlled in `packages.config`------add `-DependencyVersion highest` command. However, for net core projects which uses `packagereference`, the command does not support it so far and we cannot install the latest dependencies at the same time. Some community members also have discussed the problem [on this link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3159) and still remains to be unsolved.

Comment: As a suggestion, you can run `dotnet add package xxx(package name) -v xxx(latest version)` to update the dependency to the latest version. And if you still want this feature, you could suggest a feature on [our User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to raise attention.

Comment: Please feel free to let us know if it helps or not and share any feedback with us:)

Comment: Also, if you have reproducable builds, it works after deleting `packages.lock.json` file.